# How to access Shopware\Core\System\SalesChannel\SalesChannelContext in Entity Related event subscribers in shopware 6?

Tags: shopware

I have built a custom subscriber in my plugin for Shopware 6 that subscribes to

`\Shopware\Core\Content\Product\ProductEvents::PRODUCT_WRITTEN_EVENT = 'product.written';`

```
public function onProductWrittenEntity(EntityWrittenEvent $event): void
{
        //$event->getContext() is returning the Shopware\Core\Framework\Context
}
```

I want to get domain URL of this current `salesChannel` having those productIds which are currently written. how can i do that?

Answer (score 5):

You can obtain the `salesChannelId` by running the following code:

```php
$event->getContext()->getSource()->getSalesChannelId()
```

With that `salesChannelId` and inserting the `SalesChannelRepository` via the `services.xml` into your Subscriber, you can load the required information from that sales-channel.

Comment: Could you add an explanation? How will this help the OP?

Comment: I don't understand...that's the answer to the question, that's how you can access the sales channel. You mean to tell him to load the salesChannel repository through services.xml and use this repository search with this provided sales channel id as criteria to get the salesChannel ? he already knows this.

Comment: The OP may know this but other people looking at this answer for the first time, with the same issue may not. That is why it's important to explain your method.

Answer (score 2):

When you edit the products over the API or inside the administration, you are in a "admin context", that means no sales-channel is available. This is because your changes are globally and you are not limited to a specific sales-channel.

The `SalesChannelContext` is only available if the action that was triggered originated in the storefront or came over the store-api.

Long story short:
You can't access the salesChannelContext from the EntityWrittenEvent, as most of the times there is no specific SalesChannel, where the event was triggered.

Maybe you can explain your use case a little bit more, so we can suggest alternatives.

Comment: I would like to get domain details of current `SalesChannel`

Answer (score 1):

in case someone run in this Problem:
You can for example Subscribe to the Event "SalesChannelContextResolvedEvent". Store all the Data in a variable as type array (Argument2 from the construct, "$this->saleschannelContext"). And call it in where ever you need it, for example an other event (you can call it so -> "$this->salechannelContext").

```
 public function __construct(EntityRepository $discountExtensionRepository){
    $this->discountExtensionRepository = $discountExtensionRepository;
    $this->salechannelContext = array();
}

public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array{
    return [
        SalesChannelContextResolvedEvent::class => "onPageLoaded",
        ProductEvents::PRODUCT_LOADED_EVENT => 'onProductsLoaded'
        
    ];
}
public function onPageLoaded(SalesChannelContextResolvedEvent $event){
    $this->salechannelContext = $event->getSaleschannelContext();
}
public function onProductsLoaded(EntityLoadedEvent $event):void{
     dump($this->salechannelContext);
}
```

Probably not the best practice way because i guess there is a way to get it directly from die Product event, but it is one way of manys.

[EDIT]: You can get all Storefront and Product informations with this event.

```
use Shopware\Core\System\SalesChannel\Entity\SalesChannelEntityLoadedEvent;
 public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array{
    return [
        'sales_channel.product.loaded' => 'onSalesChannelLoaded'
        
    ];
}
public function onSalesChannelLoaded(SalesChannelEntityLoadedEvent $event):void{
```